# Accounting Data Warehouse Design Question

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, olap, accounting

The finance module in our ERP has a general ledger and sub-ledgers (accounts receivable, accounts payable etc.). All the sub-ledgers are rolled up into the GL. Standard accounting schema I believe

I have already built a fact_general_ledger table and the business now requires reporting on AP and AR.

The end goal would be to do a reconciliation between the GL and AP/AR and give more granularity into the journal postings for AP/AR

Should AP/AR be facts or dimensions?

I feel AP/AR are fact tables and they can be joined onto the GL to then give a cross comparison and help with reconciliation

However, I know joining two fact tables is asking for trouble

What is the best design practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a transactions table, with an account dimension, where amounts are recorded with + or - signs according to direction, and the accounts dimension takes care of the rolling up of accounts into larger categories.

AP & AR are now just queries for totals of a single account or account category.

Comment: This is my plan - to make a fact_AR table. However, if I want to reconcile this to the GL, I'd need to join this to the Fact_Ledger table and generally it's not a good idea to join two fact tables? I have however seen this done before

Comment: You don’t need to join. Each fact will have an amount, a date, an account, some description, etc. If it’s a transfer between accounts (eg from bank account to accounts payable), that’s 2 transactions, one plus and one minus. Querying account totals is just a matter of rolling it up.

Comment: Ok thanks. However in the OLTP we have a separate AR and GL tables. Once AR has been validated it is manually posted to the GL. Because of the manual  posting the values in both might not be the same due to errors in the posting process. This is why AR and GL need to be separate but will also need to be joined to each other for reconciliation.